# Entity Framework - Many Many-To-Many Relationships

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, many-to-many

I'm trying to use EF to relate products to transactions. Currently it allows me to only map the same transaction to on product only once.

For example, in a transaction, trying to add two of the same product doesn't work. It will only ever store one mapping?

Is it possible to do this? Or should I just create a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

EF does not allow you to add duplicates to the many to many relationships. The join table should only contain the primary keys of the participating tables as the PK of the table.

You can workaround this problem by mapping the join table as an entity and creating an auto incremented id as the PK of the join table.

```
public class ProductTransaction
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public int TransactionId { get; set; }

    public Product Product { get; set; }

    public Transaction Transaction { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductTransaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}

public class Transaction
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductTransaction> Products { get; set; }
}
```